# In mongodb 2.4 replicaset, primary has "syncingTo" set

Tags: mongodb

We have a replicaset consisting of a primary, a secondary, and an arbiter. I was upgrading them, following the instructions on the [mongodb website](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-upgrade/#upgrade-a-replica-set-from-mongodb-2-2-to-mongodb-2-4).

Here's what I did:

1. Shut down mongod on arbiter, upgrade mongod on arbiter, start mongod on arbiter.
2. Shut down mongod on secondary, upgrade mongod on secondary, start mongod on secondary.
3. (I forgot to call rs.stepDown() on the primary as recommended...) Shut down mongod on primary, upgrade mongod on primary, start mongod on primary.
4. Call rs.stepDown() on secondary to allow the primary to step up again.

While I did forget to call rs.stepDown() on the primary before shutting the primary down, I don't think that's the problem because stepDown is only supposed to speed up fail-over.

Right now, both the primary and the secondary show that they're syncing to each other. Should I be worried about this? Everything else seems to work.

Here's the results of rs.status():

```
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : "primary:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 1,
        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
        "uptime" : 3274,
        "optime" : {
            "t" : 1367879796,
            "i" : 6
        },
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-05-06T22:36:36Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-05-06T22:35:06Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "pingMs" : 1,
        "syncingTo" : "secondary:27017"
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "arbiter:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 7,
        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
        "uptime" : 3571,
        "self" : true
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "name" : "secondary:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 3570,
        "optime" : {
            "t" : 1367879796,
            "i" : 6
        },
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-05-06T22:36:36Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-05-06T22:35:06Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "pingMs" : 6,
        "syncingTo" : "primary:27017"
    }
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?  There was a display bug in 2.0 where the `syncingTo` status would still show on primaries that used to be secondaries: [SERVER-3616](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3616).  This is confusing, but only a display issue.

Comment: I'm using MongoDB version 2.4

Comment: What exact version of MongoDB + O/S is this? (eg. 2.4.3 on Windows 7).  The details are helpful to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: db version v2.4.3, 
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3, 
Ubuntu 12.10 (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-17-generic x86_64)